# What's the difference between settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and django.contrib.auth.get_user_model?

Tags: django

I've found no answer for my question anywhere. So, what's the difference between the variable set in settings file and the function from auth module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the get_user_model method returns the actual user model, while settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL returns only the string that is the name/path of the model.

Comment: Yes indeed. One is a setting (a string) and the other returns the class based on this setting.